# Why isn't there an option to view Answered Questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-exchange, accepted-answer

With this site (and other Stack sites) boasting their percentage of questions answered, why is there no option to view them explicitly? I think that if there were an option, 'Answered' it would be very useful for those interested in just picking up tid bits of useful, correct answers that's tagged to their interests.

Comment: Are you talking about searching answered questions?

Comment: Yes. I thought I'd made that clear, sorry.

Comment: Go to `<site>/search`, then click on the `Advanced Search Tips` link to the right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can search answered questions for particular tag using advanced search:

[`[sql] answers:1`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D%20answers:1)

or for questions which have accepted answer

[`[sql] hasaccepted:yes`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D+hasaccepted%3Ayes)

You can find all search tools from *Advanced Search Tips* available at the right side on the search page.

Comment: `isaccepted:yes` will return accepted _answers_. If you want questions with accepted answers try `hasaccepted:yes`

Comment: @Yannis - Ahh just updated.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It would be handy for people new to this (such as myself) if the option were with the **'Questions','Tags','Users','Badges'** and **'Unanswered'** buttons. I don't think it's _that_ specific to require an Advanced Search, no more than a search for Unanswered questions anyway.

Comment: does this apply to all sites part of the Stack Exchange?

Comment: @RobertEnglish yes of course..